# Is "Smegheads" useable as a term for Red Dwarf fans?

Tags: terminology, red-dwarf

"Star Trek" fans are called "Trekkies". Is "Smegheads" useable as a term for Red Dwarf fans, such as the following?

> There's more Trekkies than there are Smegheads.

Comment: Aw, too late to the party. Oh well.

Comment: @MrLister - Sorry smeghead. [Gotta be faster](http://moviesludge.tumblr.com/post/49057979204)

Comment: Only if you can do it like this... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RXKlC8ph7mM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a word, no. The preferred fandom name for Red Dwarf fans (for themselves) is

> "[Dwarfer](http://reddwarf.wikia.com/wiki/Dwarfer)".

Referring to oneself as a smeghead would be funny, but inaccurate.

---

Examples include

> *In any case, the key to a successful grassroots marketing campaign is
> to put the product in front of as many people as possible. And boy did
> we ever. **From the rabid Dwarfer to the casual fan**, we got a simply
> bunches of folks playing the game... and by simply bunches, of course
> I'm talking about veritable oodles.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Roleplaying Report | Features | Red Dwarf - The Official website](http://www.reddwarf.co.uk/features/history/roleplaying-report/)</sup></sub>

and

> ***Hattie rattles off fifty taxing questions specifically designed to
> shake even the most ardent Dwarfer's confidence.** While our
> barely-legible answers are tallied backstage, Hattie swiftly returns
> for her Q&A. As is customary at such events, she opens by asking if
> anyone has the first question, but warns, "I can't answer any personal
> problems".*
>
> <sub><sup>[Dimension Jump XV | Features | Red Dwarf - The Official Website](http://www.reddwarf.co.uk/features/reports/dimension-jump-15/)</sup></sub>

Comment: *Star Trek* fans **call themselves** Trekkers but **are called** Trekkies by non-fans. The OP asked for a term analogous to Trekkies. If the *Red Dwarf* fans call themselves Dwarfers, what should **we** call them? I haven't heard the word Smegheads before, but it sounds perfect.

Comment: @user14111 - I've seen the term applied to wannabe Dwarfers, but not applied to fans themselves.

Comment: @user14111 - The [Trekkie vs. Trekker debate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trekkie#Trekkie_vs._Trekker) rages on, on the internet.

Comment: Ironically, the Dwarfer in the first link has a tshirt saying "Smeg Head".

Comment: @Andrewgrimm - The irony was not lost on me.

Comment: @user14111, Smeghead is a derogatory term. Unless a person or group has, themselves, chosen to own such a term to refer to themselves, using such a derogatory term to refer to a person or group would be considered to be an insult, or at least viewed negatively.

Comment: @Makyen The guy in the picture wearing the "SMEGG HEAD" T-shirt is apparently using the term to refer to himself.

Comment: @user14111 - What makes you think that?

Comment: @user14111, He may be, he may not. Any such term can have varying levels of emotional attachment to different people depending on how it is used and who is using it to whom. It is generally better to stay away from using such unless you are within the "in" group and have heard/seen it used enough times to get a feel for what others are comfortable with.  Depending on the word, how it is used and the user, with a single word the emotional attachments can vary from deeply insulting and a term of endearment.